# How to get branch and tag contents with egit Github plugin?

Tags: java, github-api

I am using [egit-github](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core) API for going over github repositories. I am trying to get content of branches and tags for a particular repository.

With [Repository Service](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/service/RepositoryService.java) you can get hold of the branches and tags; as of type [RepositoryBranch](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/RepositoryBranch.java) or [RepositoryTag](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/RepositoryTag.java) respectively.

However if I want to inspect the contents of branches or tags, I do not know how to get them. For example you can use [ContentsService](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/service/ContentsService.java); but you need a type [IRepositoryIdProvider](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/IRepositoryIdProvider.java); and its not clear how to get that from branches or tags in this API.

So how do I traverse the contents of the branches and tags using [egit-github](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core) API. Do I have to use some other API; or parse JSON responses from GitHub myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Javadoc for [egit-github](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/tree/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core) is a bit sparse; and is just a Java wrapper for Github API. So reading the REST API documentation from Github would be recommended.

[For finding content of branches or tags of a certain repository, the API provides a string argument `ref` that could be used to supply both tag name and branch name. It also has a path variable which is a way of getting the contents of a certain directory in a repository. If you do not provide it then by default the contents of the root folder of the repository for the tag or the branch are sent back.](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/#get-contents)

In the egit Java API the contents for the branch or the tag can be accessed using the [getContents(IRepositoryIdProvider repository, String path, String ref)](https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github/blob/master/org.eclipse.egit.github.core/src/org/eclipse/egit/github/core/service/ContentsService.java#L125) method of the ContentsService class. Just pass the respective branch or tag name, along with path of the directory to which you are looking for contents, or just `null` in case you want only the contents of the root directory.